# Extremely basic media query not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This has me stumped. This works fine in browsers (tested Chrome, Firefox, and Safari), but doesn't work in Chrome emulator, Chrome mobile, or Firefox mobile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta title="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      div {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My original problem was more complex, but even boiling it down to the simplest form it's not working. Tried the above with different combinations such as `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`, different viewport meta tags, adding `only screen` to the media query, other tags than plain `div`s, etc.

My original problem surfaced when doing work with Web Components + ShadowDOM, but it doesn't seem to be related to those. Made sure to bust all my caches while testing.

Am I going nuts?

Comment: Have you tried a value other than 900px?

Comment: Try putting 'and' between 'media' and the max-width. Also style should really be in the head (or linked as css)

Comment: Just tried 500px, added `<style>` to `<head>`, and added `screen and` in between media and max-width. No luck. Will update my post with the new code.

Comment: @Kevin which mobile device are you using to test the chrome browser? Many are wider than 900 now. mine is 1440 for example.. The quirktools [screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) tool usually keeps up to date with device sizes .. worth a try?

Comment: There must be something wrong with how you're testing. It works [perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsNy8.png). Might not be related, but make sure your zoom level is at `100%`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Found the issue and answered my own question. Interesting that browsers are smart enough to work without `name` set, but not mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow I'm dumb. Had a typo in the meta tag. Should be `name` instead of `title`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```